# How to dynamically add months in Apache drill

Tags: apache-drill

Query that works:

```
select 
  a,
  DATE_ADD(date '2015-05-15', interval '1' month)
from
(
 select '1' a, INSERTED_AT from dfs.data.bi_interaction limit 3
);
```

Query that does not work:

```
select 
  a,
  DATE_ADD(date '2015-05-15', interval a month)
from
(
 select '1' a, INSERTED_AT from dfs.data.bi_interaction limit 3
);
```

Any workaround?

Comment: share sample data (_on which you are performing this query_) & drill version.

Comment: Sample data does not matter as the table is just used to have any rows. Drill version 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

The second query doesn't work because the DATE_ADD function doesn't support a column as the interval argument. If you have a use case for that please get in touch with the Drill team on the mailing lists here: https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/